# Reset on lockup, by discrete analog components

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, semiconductors

Way back when in the 80s/90s in a C64 magazine was an electronics project described. By adding a piece of code, the C64 would send a signal (pulse of power) to the electronics.  If that stopped, the circuit would trigger a reset signal to the C64.

It only contained a few capacitors, diodes, and transistors.

I wonder:

1. How did it work / was built?
2. Could it be adapted to a microcontroller? (Hard reset it by cutting the power for a while.)
3. Could it be made in a way that if the power is sent for too long (microcontroller freezes on sending the alive pulse) that it also resets?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a kind of watchdog timer. We have that function built into microcontrollers and discrete chips which perform that function autonomously. Generally they just pulse a reset input (or several reset inputs in a circuit) rather than interrupting power, but making a device that interrupts power for a set period of time on the absence of "keep alive" pulses is not a challenging task, just (thankfully) usually unnecessary.

There are plenty of ways of doing it. 555, microcontroller, 74HCxxx monostable multivibrator etc.

In fact, some use a windowing function so that DC levels are rejected AND pulses that are wildly outside of the expected frequency are also rejected.

Comment: Ah, that seems it. Thing is, I want to build it without using chips. How would I go about that?

Comment: Something like an AC-coupled transistor that resets a capacitor that otherwise continuously charges through a resistor. Once the capacitor voltage reaches a threshold it triggers a one-shot that interrupts power for a set period of time. A pretty boring combination of building blocks, that is hard to justify with availability of better ways.

Comment: @BizzKeryear You make a resettable monostable out of transistors, rather than a ready made chip.  A 555 is just a bunch of transistors packaged together.

Comment: @BizzKeryear -- One guy I follow is Jack Ganssle, who does an email newsletter I get, and he has some really good resources on embedded.  He wrote two pieces on watchdogs, here --   [Designing Great Watchdog Timers For Embedded Systems](http://www.ganssle.com/watchdogs.htm),  and here --     [Watchdogs Redux](http://www.ganssle.com/articles/watchdogsredux.htm).  The two microcontrollers watching each other (in first article) is one of my favorites. Enjoy!

Comment: Spehro... As a pro dev from the software world, I consider this to be among the more important EE embedded topics. This question should be reopened, IMHO!