# Is there any MPU where the watchdog has its own clock?

Tags: microcontroller, clock, watchdog

Forgive me for sort of meandering towards the question. I feel that all is pertinent, so please don't "improve" my question by removing all of its "flavor"!

I was lamenting over the poor state of software today (as a Senior Software Developer who is still trying to get into embedded and flashlight technologies), and a question [Reset on lockup, by discrete analog components](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/624448/146624), which I will paraphrase as, "Would you please show me an external watchdog circuit".  IMHO, I do not think this should have been closed (they said it was too broad, but there are plenty of questions on this site that are basically "show me a circuit that can do this.")  In fact, the question was answered by [Spehro Pefhany](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/35530/spehro-pefhany), which to me is proof that the question is worthwhile (and should be reopened).

Now, I know that good watchdog circuits are thankless, and you only get noticed if it doesn't work correctly -- that's not the way the world should be, of course -- but isn't it right that we try to do a quality job?  So isn't that part of being professional Electrical Engineers?  Or are watchdog circuits considered optional because operating systems have paved the way to acceptance of a lowered standard where people expect failure and rebooting as just a part of life now?

Anyway. I had read afresh the two articles by Jack Ganssle (I love his email newsletter).  Jack wrote two pieces on watchdogs, here -- [Designing Great Watchdog Timers For Embedded Systems](http://www.ganssle.com/watchdogs.htm), and here -- [Watchdogs Redux](http://www.ganssle.com/articles/watchdogsredux.htm).

And after reading both articles again, I thought that, if the crystal stops oscillating or the chip otherwise hangs, an internal watchdog would be dead, too (and that shouldn't be).  Lots of Microchip microcontrollers have their own oscillators... What would it take to add a second oscillator, on-chip, just for the watchdog, to give it a greater level of independence and reliability? Somebody, please make this a reality!

Comment: I believe what you’re asking for can be fulfilled by a “clock watchdog” which monitors a clock signal and if it stops toggling fails over to an internal RC oscillator. I worked with one of these once but I cannot for the life of me remember which chip it was.

Comment: @Bryan -- Yes, and thanks for that... But I think that I'm looking for it to be implemented internally, inside the chip. I think what you're talking about is a circuit external to the chip. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've never encountered one outside the chip. To clarify: I worked with a microcontroller that had a "clock failsafe monitor" in it (just remembered the name!). I'm not sure I'd trust this part outside the chip - installing anything in the path of your clock signal just sounds like a recipe for trouble, I'd trust the chip manufacturer to get it done right. Now that I remember the name let me see if I can find the chip (or its friends)

Comment: If the chip latches up, all bets are off. The gpio that controls the linear accelerator might be in any state. You’d want a hardware watchdog as well otherwise your chips may get burnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is reality. This feature is often implemented in microcontrollers. Just as an example, the atMega328 has a separate 128 kHz low frequency oscillator for the hardware watchdog. The datasheet says:

> Warning: Using the 128 kHz internal oscillator as the system oscillator and Watchdog Timer simultaneously is not recommended as this defeats one of the purposes of the Watchdog Timer

So the watchdog clock is designed as desired

Comment: Thank you. I never thought of the low frequency oscillator that way, but that makes sense now. How about other microcontrollers / micro manufacturers?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD You asked for any MCU. It should be no surprise that many other MCUs also have a watchdog. Even small STM32 MCUs have more than one watchdog, one fully independent, and one that runs on main clock. They also have clock security system that can be used to switch to internal clock source if external source has a problem. So they can be used to catch both software and hardware bugs/errors.

Comment: @Justme -- From Jack Ganssle's first article, "The best watchdog is one that doesn't rely on the processor or its software."  I don't know why I translated this into my assumption that watchdogs depend on the clock of the processor in which they reside. I guess I retract my question and rather intend to pose a new question "How are external watchdogs better than internal watchdogs?" ... or perhaps ... "How many different ways can a microcontroller go bad where the watchdog fails to either function or recognize the need for reset?" I still want to drill down on this, because I think it matters!

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion in the comments there also exists "clock watchdog" implementations in some IC's, take for example Microchips "Failsafe Clock monitor":

[image: FSCM from microchips docs]

Source from their documentation here: https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-BA964748-63AC-4D4B-AD5F-E96EAA995DF8-en-US-17/index.html?GUID-6C4D7D8A-4240-4725-A2F6-76A73A20FFFB

When I worked with this part before I found it was able to detect failures of an oscillator and swap over to a backup oscillator. The CPU will still be running and can handle the clock failure as best as possible.

Comment: Glad to hear it actually works. Have you ever had to use an external watchdog?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Not personally, but I worked with some people who had to use one because the internal one on this stellaris (i think?) chip had some issues. They seem easy enough to use - though do spend a lot of time thinging about how you service them. I saw a setup that used an interrupt to service the watchdog, and of course the cpu gets stuck in a loop and the interrupt blindly services the watchdog because it still can.